# how can casperjs/phantomjs work with websocket?

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a page using **websocket** and it works well in Chrome.

Now I am trying to test it with **casperjs/phantomjs**.

However it seems that websoket won't work at all.

Does casperjs/phantomjs support websoket? I mean the page send data and get data with webscoket, not using casperjs/phantomjs to send/get data.

Is there any way to **test that if websoket works**?

```
//can load file but seems not work    
casper.waitForResource("socketConnection.js", function() {
    this.echo('socket has been loaded.');
    this.wait(14000, function() {
        this.echo("I've waited for some seconds.");
        this.capture('socket.png');
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor WebSocket communication in Phantom.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642875/how-to-monitor-websocket-communication-in-phantom-js)

Comment: In fact, I saw that question before I ask this one. My problem now is not to monitor websocket communication. I want it to run as in the chrome,( just run, send and get) but it seems not working at all. Do I have to proxy the WebSocket then it can work?

Comment: As I said in the first part of my answer, the support for WebSockets depends on your PhantomJS version. Which one do you have?

Comment: That is strange. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. Also, are you sure that CasperJS uses the correct PhantomJS executable? If CasperJS is installed through npm, it may include an older version internally and use that.

Comment: Yes, that may be the quetions.`CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3 at /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec, using phantomjs version 1.9.8`.But, where can i change it, i didn't realy find it thought i have installed phantom@2.0.0 .

Comment: Try to put the path to the newer PhantomJS version to the front of your PATH environment variable.