# How to get response body for a websocket request Using SlimerJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, phantomjs, browser-automation, slimerjs

I am trying to get response.body for a websocket request Using SlimerJS. Could not find an api page / blog mentioning that. Any pointers ?

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var url = "https://****"; 
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"; 
page.captureContent = [ /text\/plain/ ]; // web socket req's mime type. 
var mimeTypes = {}; 
var timer = 0; 

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {

    if(response.stage == "end") {

        if(mimeTypes[response.contentType] === undefined) {
            mimeTypes[response.contentType] = 1; 
        } else {
            mimeTypes[response.contentType] = ++mimeTypes[response.contentType]; 
        }
            // ** no response body is displayed ** 
            if(response.url.indexOf("websocket-requri.ws") !== -1){
                console.log(response.id, response.url, response.contentType, response.body.substring(0,50)); // no response is displayed
            }


    }
};

page.open(url, function(status){

})
```

Comment: WebSocket traffic does not appear as resource requests, so you can't use `page.onResourceReceived`.

Comment: ok, i did this finally. it worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126102/381786